# Why is the calculate function giving different results for same expression when written by directly referencing a measure or its components?

Tags: powerbi

I was running a measure wherein I wanted to compare the output of the `gasoline` product against all other products in a table visual in Power BI. I wrote 2 measures which were intended to give the same results but, they both populated the same numbers but, differently in the visual.

```
Demand Volume 2 = CALCULATE([Total Volume],filter(Product_Table, \
(Product_Table[Concept]="Demand" || Product_Table[Concept]="Export") && Product_Table[Product]="Gasoline"))
```

The initial part of the formula was captured under a new measure called `Demand Volume`

```
Demand Volume = [Total Volume],filter(Product_Table, \
    (Product_Table[Concept]="Demand" || Product_Table[Concept]="Export")
```

And, the new formula Demand Volume 3 was created as follows -

```
Demand Volume 3 = CALCULATE([Demand Volume],Product_Table[Product]="Gasoline")
```

I am unable to understand why `Demand Volume 2` populates only against `gasoline` while `Demand Volume 3` is able to populate against all rows.

Any help is highly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you just took the value of Gasoline in the measure Demand Volume 3.
You dint use the filter condition on the table.

Please try using the measure as below

```
Demand Volume 3 = CALCULATE([Demand Volume],FILTER(Product_Table,Product_Table[Product]="Gasoline"))
```